# IntStream map function behavior

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I have a small piece of code that counts number of positive, negative and zero values from a given array. I can do it easily with Java 7 by iterating over the array and counting the number of positive, negative and zero values. But with Java 8 streams, is it correct to write the conditions in map function? Currently this code iterates only once and skips the rest of values of array.

```
static void calculatePositiveNegativeAndZero(int[] arr) {
    AtomicInteger positive = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicInteger zero = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicInteger negative = new AtomicInteger(0);
    int len = arr.length;
    Arrays.stream(arr)
            .parallel()
            .map(i -> i > 0 ? positive.getAndIncrement() : (i == 0 ? zero.getAndIncrement() : negative.getAndIncrement()));

    System.out.println(positive.doubleValue()/len);
    System.out.println(negative.doubleValue()/len);
    System.out.println(zero.doubleValue()/len);
}
```

Comment: you could [accept and answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it really helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also handle this by making a wrapper class. And you don't need to use AtomicInteger. With **Java 10** I figured it out in following way.

```
var wrapper = new Object(){ int positive = 0, negative = 0, zero = 0; };
Arrays.stream(arr)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(i -> { int tmp = i > 0 ? wrapper.positive++ : (i == 0 ? wrapper.zero++ : wrapper.negative++);});
```

Comment: Thanks @Eran for giving the idea of creating a local variable to hold the result of ternary operation.

Comment: well in such a case you can simplify this to `int[] arr = { -1, -2, -3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2 };

        int[] ans = new int[3];

        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(x -> ans[Integer.signum(x) + 1] += 1);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));`

Answer (score 2):

You have no terminal operation in your stream pipeline, so it shouldn't be executed at all. You can use `forEach` instead of `map`:

```
Arrays.stream(arr)
        .parallel()
        .forEach(i -> {
             int k = i > 0 ? positive.getAndIncrement() : (i == 0 ? zero.getAndIncrement() : negative.getAndIncrement());
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out towards absence of terminal operation in stream.When using stream.forEach() it says "bad return type in lambda expression. int cannot be converted to void"

Comment: @FaysalMehmood strange. I was sure it would ignore the `int` value returned by the ternary conditional expression. Anyway, I updated the code to make it pass compilation, though it's a bit uglier now.

Comment: A ternary expression is not an [Expression Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) and hence, cannot be used as a consumer. But you can turn it into a method invocation and remove the code duplication at the same time: `.forEach(i -> (i > 0? positive: i == 0? zero: negative).getAndIncrement())`. Since a method invocation is an Expression Statement, it is permitted as consumer (then, indeed dropping the resulting `int` value).

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing without `AtomicXXX` a bit a different way:

```
Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Integer::signum,
                    Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println("positive = " + map.get(1) + " negative = " + map.get(-1) + " zero = " + map.get(0));
```

Comment: Thank-you @Eugene for providing another approach.

Comment: *Know your library*. This solution starts to shine when you use [`.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::signum, Collectors.counting()));`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#signum-int-)…

Comment: Or `Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(Integer::signum).collect(Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));`, which reduces the boxing overhead as it creates at most three `Integer` instances (the canonical representations of `-1`, `0`, and `1`).

Comment: @Holger well... it took a while to understand how `Integer::signum` is implemented, thank you for the hint, I bet I will forget about this in a month.

Comment: It doesn’t matter, how `Integer::signum` has been implemented, as long as it is simpler to call it than to implement it yourself. That would apply, even if it’s implementation code looked exactly like yours. Besides that, it might also be known as an intrinsic operation to the JVM’s optimizer, regardless of its source code. And `.mapToObj(Integer::signum)` reduces the boxing overhead because of its *contract* of always returning only either of `-1`, `0`, and `1`…